# String indices must be integers while parsing dictionary in column

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I got some problem encountered with this error while trying to split a movie data set (csv file) with Genres column filled with dictionary type, for example like [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, ...]. I'm trying to get all the "name" value. I have also searched about this but don't know how to fix it correctly. Is there anyone has a solution for this.

```
import pandas
import numpy
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot

data = pandas.read_csv('Downloads/tmdb_5000_movies.csv')

def pipe_flatten_names(k):                 
    return '|'.join([x["name"] for x in k])
data['genres'] = data['genres'].apply(pipe_flatten_names)
```

Below is how the error looks like

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-d02b9c57fd2e> in <module>()
      2 #    return '|'.join([i.get["name"] for i in x])
      3 
----> 4 data['genres'] = data['genres'].apply(pipe_flatten_names)
      5 
      6 liste_genres = set()                               #Combine all the 
genres collected into a list

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3190             else:
   3191                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3192                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3193 
   3194         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-21-6b978a26968e> in pipe_flatten_names(k)
      1 def abc(k):
      2     ds = (x["name"] for x in k)#Function collect genres name from Genres column
----> 3     return '|'.join(ds)

<ipython-input-21-6b978a26968e> in <genexpr>(.0)
  1 def pipe_flatten_names(k):
----> 2     ds = (x["name"] for x in k)#Function collect genres name from Genres column
  3     return '|'.join(ds)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Shouldn't `i.get["name"]` be `i.get("name")`?

Comment: Can you show us what does your CSV look like?

Comment: It seems like `data['genres']` is returning a series of string, and not list. That is why when you try to call `apply` on each element, a string is encountered. We can have a better idea if you show us how your csv and dataframe look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the Apply method, your function passed as a parameter will be called once for each data contained in the specific column of your CSV used to call the function Apply, with it's parameter beeing the data itself. For example:

If my CSV look like:

```
+-----+-----------+
|  id |      name |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 |    Action |
+-----+-----------+
|   2 | Adventure |
+-----+-----------+
```

In each call for your function, the date will be passed as a string, so if i call

```
x["name"].Apply(func)
```

func will be called 2 times with the parameters Action and Adventure as a string, and you are string to iterate this string (`k`) passing a string as an index, hence the error.
If i understood correctly, you have on your CSV representing a string representation of a  dictionary, so you will have to convert it using `ast` built-in library, and then read each element of the dict. Try this:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import ast
data = pandas.read_csv('Downloads/tmdb_5000_movies.csv', sep=';')

def pipe_flatten_names(k):                 
    genres = ast.literal_eval(k)
    return '|'.join(x['name'] for x in genres)
data['genres'] = data['genres'].apply(pipe_flatten_names)
```

I also changed the separator from the CSV file, because if your CSV is separated by ',' and the dictionary uses ',' they will become messed up, so try using a separator that is not contained in the dict syntax